# Remaining time until next interval is not rounded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have to execute background tasks at certain time and if you look at my output below, `double seconds` returns not accurate/rounded number. I have to execute the task exactly at 2:30:00 AM, not before, like 2:29:59 AM.

Output with the problem:

```
Open time: 12/7/2019 2:25:00 AM | Next interval: 12/7/2019 2:30:00 AM | 100.8130476474762
Open time: 12/7/2019 2:25:00 AM | Next interval: 12/7/2019 2:29:59 AM | 95.77832388877869
Open time: 12/7/2019 2:25:00 AM | Next interval: 12/7/2019 2:30:00 AM | 83.98297166824341
Open time: 12/7/2019 2:25:00 AM | Next interval: 12/7/2019 2:30:00 AM | 74.9000027179718
```

```cs
public class BotHelper
{
    public static int KlineIntervalToSeconds(KlineInterval interval)
    {
        return interval switch
        {
            KlineInterval.OneMinute => 1 * 60,
            KlineInterval.FiveMinutes => 5 * 60,
            KlineInterval.OneHour => 60 * 60,
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Not supported interval."),
        };
    }

    private static double DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime) -
                new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
    }

    public static double RemainingSecondsUntilTheNextTimeInterval(KlineInterval interval)
    {
        int minutes = KlineIntervalToSeconds(interval) / 60;
        double currentTimeUnixTimestamp = DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
        return (minutes * 60) - (currentTimeUnixTimestamp % (minutes * 60));
    }
}

public void Start(Bot bot)
{
    var lastKnownKline = _client.GetKlines(bot.CryptoPair.Symbol, bot.TimeInterval.Interval, limit: 2).Data.First();
    _subscription = _socketClient.SubscribeToKlineUpdates(bot.CryptoPair.Symbol, bot.TimeInterval.Interval, async data =>
    {
        if (data.Data.Final)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Final | Open time: {data.Data.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()}");
        }

        if (lastKnownKline.OpenTime != data.Data.OpenTime)
        {
            // Static
            _logger.LogError($"Static | Open time: {lastKnownKline.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | {lastKnownKline.Close}");
        }
        else if (lastKnownKline.OpenTime == data.Data.OpenTime && lastKnownKline.Close != data.Data.Close)
        {
            // Real time
            if (!_locked)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Real time | Open time: {data.Data.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | {data.Data.Close}");
                _locked = true;

                double seconds = BotHelper.RemainingSecondsUntilTheNextTimeInterval(redisBot.Interval);
                _logger.LogWarning($"Open time: {data.Data.OpenTime.ToLocalTime()} | Next interval: {DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(seconds).ToLocalTime()} | {seconds}");
                BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Checker(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));

                _locked = false;
            }
        }

        lastKnownKline = data.Data.ToKline();
    }).Data;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why to you divide `KlineIntervalToSeconds` by `60` when you just multiply it by `60` again each time you use it (in `RemainingSecondsUntilTheNextTimeInterval`)?

Comment: @RufusL `(currentTimeUnixTimestamp % (minutes * 60)` returns the passed seconds and `(minutes * 60) - (currentTimeUnixTimestamp % (minutes * 60))` the remaining seconds until the interval.

Comment: Yeah, but my question is why don't you just store the seconds in the first place and avoid all the multiplication and division? The lines become: `int seconds = KlineIntervalToSeconds(interval);` and then later, `return seconds - currentTimeUnixTimestamp % seconds;`

Comment: @RufusL, sure. Style-wise it's fine.